# Analysis Services date formats

Tags: windows-server-2003, ssas

I've created a simple Reporting Services report that contains a tablix which sources its data from an MDX query against an Analysis Services instance. The result set for the query contains some dates.  When I set the datasource of the dataset to TESTSERVER1 the dates are displayed in UK format - dd/mm/yyyy.  However when I set the datasoure connection string to TEST SERVER2 the dates appear in US format - mm/dd/yyyy.

The setting in Control Panel > Regional and Language Options > Standards and formats is English (United Kingdom).

I'm wondering what could be causing the dates to display differently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was that the Regional and Language Options on TESTSERVER2 for the service account used to run the Analysis Services instance were set to English United States.  When a user logged into the server the language settings were Enlgish UK, but it looks like these settings are profile specific and Analysis Services uses the settings for the account used to run it.